# No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Tags: python, github-actions

Following a tutorial to practice using GitHub actions but I am getting an error despite seemingly having what the instructor has. Will simply echo "test", install wandb, and print the wandb version.

Getting the following error in GitHub actions:

```
Run pip install -r requirements.txt
  pip install -r requirements.txt
  python ci.py
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

All the files are in the repository and in the same **gregorywmorris/w-b-cicd/.github/workflows/ folder**. What does this error mean?

**ci.yaml**

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo

on: [push]

jobs:
  my-first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: hello
        run: |
          echo "Test"
      - name: run python script
        run: |
          python pip install -r requirements.txt
          python ci.py
```

Changed the first run line to `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` and got the same error. Also failed with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

**ci.py**

```
import wandb


print(f'The version of wandb is: {wandb.__version__}')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
wandb
```

Comment: Which part of the error message _"ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'"_ would you like to better understand?

Comment: And have you tried `python -m pip install -r .github/workflows/requirements.txt` ?

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that adding `.github/workflows/` to both the requirements and .py file resolved the issue.

Comment: I don't know the tutorial you're following, but the setup-python action takes care of installing dependencies for you.

Comment: In hindsight, I was confused about the no such file as it did in fact exist. It didn't occur to me that it couldn't find it because I wasn't explicit about its location. This is the danger of following tutorials without a deep understanding of processes I guess. Odd that it worked for the presenter.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that's interesting, I should try without calling for the requirements file. EDIT: I need to use the requirements.txt for dependencies else it will fail.

Comment: _What does this error mean?_ It means `requirements.txt` was not found in the current directory.

Comment: @GregoryMorris: Please add the link of the tutorial in your question that you followed. If the `ci.py` and the `requriements.txt` are placed under `.github/workflows/` then what do you have at the root of the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @hakre in the comments. Need to add `.github/workflows/` to both the requirements and ci.py in the last run command.

Corrected:

```
run: |
    python -m pip install -r .github/workflows/requirements.txt
    python .github/workflows/ci.py
```

Was following the tutorial by Weights and Bias for others that may come across this issue while following the tutorial. If you place the requirements and ci.py file in the main directory, then you don't have to specify the location.